# replicating what is on the screen when printing

Tags: css

I have a project using primefaces components. But when I select File > Print preview from the browser, it is in a big mess. I did some googling and understands that we can create a print.css to resolved it. But I did not see any improvement on it.

Is there any way to replicate what is on the screen for printing?

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 25pt;
}

h1,h2,h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-top: 0.5pt solid #000;
}

th,td {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 0.5pt solid #000;
}

blockquote {
    page-break-inside: avoid
}

ul,ol,dl {
    page-break-before: avoid
}

.noprint,.noscreen,#search,#nav,#aside {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    border-bottom: 0.5pt solid #000;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 0.5pt solid #000;
}
```

Comment: It depends largely upon the CSS you're using and the user's settings. Most browsers have the option to disable background colours when printing set to off by default. How did you manipulate the print CSS file, can you post samples and a live URL? I'm afraid you really haven't provided enough information here...

Answer (score 0):

whichever css you use
for printing purpose you can use the same css but with an extra attribute

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

the element `media = "print"`

put this and your preview will work fine

Comment: I have done that but still in a mess. Not sure if I miss out anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use print.css to provide a optimized style for your print layout and order your "big mess".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

> Is there any way to replicate what is on the screen for printing?

If I get you right here, this may help you: [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/examples/scroll-analytics/